# JavaScript function parameter error

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, slideshow

I have this simple slideshow set up and it all works fine if I remove the parameters and add the class and speed manually.

If I use parameters to set the class and speed, it fails. With the first image getting the current class applied and then the dom seems to go crazy.

‘undefined’ pops up a lot although there are no errors in console.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
let pos = 0;

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    testIt('current', 5000);
});

function testIt(_class, _speed) {
   const testPara = document.querySelectorAll('.bg_imgs');

   let i;
   for(i = 0; i < testPara.length; i++) {
       testPara[i].classList.remove(_class);
   }

   pos++;


   if(pos > testPara.length) {pos = 1;}

   testPara[pos-1].classList.add(_class);

   setTimeout(_class, _speed); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetTimeout takes a function as its first param. If you are trying to delay the recursion  try:

`setTimeout(() => testIt(_class, _speed), _speed)`

Thought window.requestAnimationFrame would be a better solution. [More info on animation frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: This also works like a charm. Much prefer using arrow functions thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're sending the wrong parameters to `setTimeout`.  It should take the form `setTimeout(function, time)`, but instead, you're passing it what I assume is a string.

```
setTimeout(function() { testIt(_class, _speed); }, _speed);
```

should work